# Delphi - Why udp data packet is different?

Tags: delphi, udp, delphi-7, indy, indy-9

I want understand why the data packet received in the `Wireshark` program is different of the sent by my delphi application. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
if Pos('\x',comandoRede.Comando) > 0 then
begin

  bufferS := Explode('\x',comandoRede.Comando);

  SetLength(buffer,Length(bufferS)-1);

  for J := 0 to Length(Buffer) -1 do
  begin

    buffer[J] := StrToInt('$'+bufferS[J+1]);

  end;

    TIdUDPServer(item).SendBuffer(equipamentoRede.IP,
      StrToInt(equipamentoRede.Port),buffer,Length(buffer));

end
```

Here the content of the buffer array:

[image: Buffer]

Here the log of the `network sniffer Wireshark`

[image: Wireshark]

I've tried with the TIDUDPClient as well, but the problem is the same.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: What is the value of `bufferS` before populating `buffer`? Are you sure you are actually looking at the correct `buffer` in the debugger (and on which line is the code stopped on when viewing it?), and at the correct packet in Wireshark? I suspect you are looking at two different things. Indy does not change the data being sent.

Comment: How is SendBuffer declared in your Indy version? Does it use TIdBytes  argument or typeless var parameter?

Comment: @MBo: given the code shown, it would have to be the `var` version (Indy 9) because the `TIdBytes` version (Indy 10) does not have an explicit length parameter, it uses the array's length instead.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Well, so I suggested that author sends pointer instead of array body.

Comment: @MBo: yes, that is what must be happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Indy 9, `SendBuffer()` is declared as follows:

```
procedure SendBuffer(AHost: string; const APort: Integer; var ABuffer; const AByteCount: integer);
```

Note that the `ABuffer` is an untyped `var`.  That means you can pass *anything* to it, and it receives the memory address of whatever variable you pass in.

Your `buffer` is declared as a dynamic array (presumably, due to your use of `SetLength()`).  A dynamic array is internally implemented as a pointer to a memory block that resides elsewhere in memory.  When you pass a dynamic array variable to an untyped `var` parameter, the parameter receives the memory address of the variable itself, not the memory address of the array data that the variable points at.  That is why you are seeing "garbage" being sent on the socket - you are actually sending the bytes of the data pointer itself!  Your code *happens* to not crash, because your `buffer` length is 4 and pointers in Delphi 7 are 4 bytes in size.

In order for the `var` parameter to receive the memory address of the actual array data, you must either:

1. index into the first element of the array:

   ```
   TIdUDPServer(item).SendBuffer(..., buffer[0], Length(buffer));
   ```
2. type-cast the array variable to the appropriate pointer type (in this case, presumably `buffer` is an `array of Byte`, so use `PByte`) and then dereference the pointer:

   ```
   TIdUDPServer(item).SendBuffer(..., PByte(buffer)^, Length(buffer));
   ```